# Read and Write CSV files including unicode with Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, unicode, export

I am new to Python, and I have a question about how to use Python to read and write CSV files. My file contains like Germany, French, etc. According to my code, the files can be read correctly in Python, but when I write it into a new CSV file, the unicode becomes some strange characters.

The data is like:
[image]

And my code is:

```
import csv

f=open('xxx.csv','rb')
reader=csv.reader(f)

wt=open('lll.csv','wb')
writer=csv.writer(wt,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

wt.close()
f.close()
```

And the result is like:
[image]

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: you could encode it in base64, pythn has a module for that too.

Comment: I use this https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Comment: What source and destination encoding are you using for your files?  Unicode is not an encoding (unless you are Microsoft...but they really mean UTF-16LE).

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Thank you very much! I would like to try that.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Many thanks! I tried the code in the link, but it still does not work. In fact, everything is fine when I import data and print data in Python. But after I write them in the new csv file, the special characters change to strange thing. Do you have any idea of this?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you very much! It seems not to make changes. In fact, everything is fine when I import data and print data in Python. But after I write them in the new csv file, the special characters change to strange thing. Is it possible to be caused by language settings or computer system? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you on Windows? What encoding are you using for the files? Many windows programs that read UTF-8 files like a BOM signature at the start of a UTF-8 file.  Use the `utf-8-sig` encoding when writing the file to ensure one is written.

Comment: try "latin1" as the encoding type when you open the file ... that often will resolve the issue when dealing with european languages

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you very much! I am on Windows. But where should I specify utf-8-sig?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for you reply. where do I change the encoding type?

Comment: @RuxuanOuyang, I updated my answer below to use `utf-8-sig` when reading or writing the file to ensure a BOM signature is added to the file.  For example, if I open the file in Excel without the BOM, I get  `ç¾Žå›½äºº`, but with it I get `美国人`.

Comment: @RuxuanOuyang, Great!  Make sure to accept an answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 63):

Another alternative:

Use the code from the unicodecsv package ...

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/

```
>>> import unicodecsv as csv
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> f = BytesIO()
>>> w = csv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> _ = w.writerow((u'é', u'ñ'))
>>> _ = f.seek(0)
>>> r = csv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> next(r) == [u'é', u'ñ']
True
```

This module is API compatible with the STDLIB csv module.

Comment: This lib is amazing.

Answer (score 58):

Make sure you encode and decode as appropriate.

This example will roundtrip some example text in utf-8 to a csv file and back out to demonstrate:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

tests={'German': [u'Straße',u'auslösen',u'zerstören'], 
       'French': [u'français',u'américaine',u'épais'], 
       'Chinese': [u'中國的',u'英語',u'美國人']}

with open('/tmp/utf.csv','w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)    
    writer.writerows([tests.keys()])
    for row in zip(*tests.values()):
        row=[s.encode('utf-8') for s in row]
        writer.writerows([row])

with open('/tmp/utf.csv','r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        temp=list(row)
        fmt=u'{:<15}'*len(temp)
        print fmt.format(*[s.decode('utf-8') for s in temp])
```

Prints:

```
German         Chinese        French         
Straße         中國的            français       
auslösen       英語             américaine     
zerstören      美國人            épais
```

Comment: Basically, as long as _everything_ is encoded as Unicode, it works just fine. Thanks for driving the point home without a huge wall of code!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpul! Let me see if I understood the way it works: Even if you store your strings in Python like `u'Straße'`, they’re still (escaped as) ASCII internally (`u'Stra\xdfe'`), so that you have to translate/encode everything into UTF-8 (escaped strings) (`'Stra\xc3\x9fe'`) before writing them to a UTF-8 encoded file?

Comment: @doncherry: No, the strings are internally represented as they are encoded. If you see them as escaped ascii, that is the representation at the time or the way you need to input them.

Answer (score 30):

There is an example at the end of the [csv module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) that demonstrates how to deal with Unicode.  Below is copied directly from that [example](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#examples).  Note that the strings read or written will be Unicode strings.  Don't pass a byte string to `UnicodeWriter.writerows`, for example.

```
import csv,codecs,cStringIO

class UTF8Recoder:
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
    def next(self):
        '''next() -> unicode
        This function reads and returns the next line as a Unicode string.
        '''
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class UnicodeWriter:
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()
    def writerow(self, row):
        '''writerow(unicode) -> None
        This function takes a Unicode string and encodes it to the output.
        '''
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

with open('xxx.csv','rb') as fin, open('lll.csv','wb') as fout:
    reader = UnicodeReader(fin)
    writer = UnicodeWriter(fout,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Input (UTF-8 encoded):

```
American,美国人
French,法国人
German,德国人
```

Output:

```
"American","美国人"
"French","法国人"
"German","德国人"
```

Comment: I am still getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` on `self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])` this row. Please suggest?

Comment: @Ahsan, that row is encoding but the error is `UnicodeDecodeError`.  It implies that `s` was not Unicode to begin with, so Python 2.X is decoding it to Unicode using the default `ascii` codec.  Make sure you are passing Unicode strings to `UnicodeWriter`.

Comment: Yep, this exactly was the reason. I managed to solve this by this link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22734072/534790 Thanks! Can you please update the answer in case someone else face this same issue?

Answer (score 6):

Because `str` in python2 is `bytes` actually. So if want to write `unicode` to csv, you must encode `unicode` to `str` using `utf-8` encoding.

```
def py2_unicode_to_str(u):
    # unicode is only exist in python2
    assert isinstance(u, unicode)
    return u.encode('utf-8')
```

Use `class csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)`:

- py2

  - The `csvfile`: `open(fp, 'w')`
  - pass key and value in `bytes` which are encoded with `utf-8`

    - `writer.writerow({py2_unicode_to_str(k): py2_unicode_to_str(v) for k,v in row.items()})`
- py3

  - The `csvfile`: `open(fp, 'w')`
  - pass normal dict contains `str` as `row` to `writer.writerow(row)`

Finally code

```
import sys

is_py2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2

def py2_unicode_to_str(u):
    # unicode is only exist in python2
    assert isinstance(u, unicode)
    return u.encode('utf-8')

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    if is_py2:
        data = {u'Python中国': u'Python中国', u'Python中国2': u'Python中国2'}

        # just one more line to handle this
        data = {py2_unicode_to_str(k): py2_unicode_to_str(v) for k, v in data.items()}

        fields = list(data[0])
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)

        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        data = {'Python中国': 'Python中国', 'Python中国2': 'Python中国2'}

        fields = list(data[0])
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)

        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

### Conclusion

In python3, just use the unicode `str`.

In python2, use `unicode` handle text, use `str` when I/O occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same issue. The answer is that you are doing it right already. It is the problem of MS Excel. Try opening the file with another editor and you will notice that your encoding was successful already. To make MS Excel happy, move from UTF-8 to UTF-16. This should work:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel_tab, encoding="utf-16", **kwds):
    # Redirect output to a queue
    self.queue = StringIO.StringIO()
    self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
    self.stream = f

    # Force BOM
    if encoding=="utf-16":
        import codecs
        f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16)

    self.encoding = encoding

def writerow(self, row):
    # Modified from original: now using unicode(s) to deal with e.g. ints
    self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
    # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
    data = self.queue.getvalue()
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
    data = data.encode(self.encoding)

    # strip BOM
    if self.encoding == "utf-16":
        data = data[2:]

    # write to the target stream
    self.stream.write(data)
    # empty queue
    self.queue.truncate(0)

def writerows(self, rows):
    for row in rows:
        self.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't respond to Mark above, but I just made one modification which fixed the error that was caused if data in the cells was not unicode, e.g. float or int data.  I replaced this line into the UnicodeWriter function: "self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") if type(s)==types.UnicodeType else s for s in row])" so that it became:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
       self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()
    def writerow(self, row):
        '''writerow(unicode) -> None
        This function takes a Unicode string and encodes it to the output.
        '''
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") if type(s)==types.UnicodeType else s for s in row])
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

You will also need to "import types".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best answer, but it's probably the most self-contained answer and also the funniest.

[UTF7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) is a 7-bit ASCII encoding of unicode.   It just so happens that UTF7 makes no special use of commas, quotes, or whitespace.   It just passes them through from input to output.   So really it makes no difference if you UTF7-encode first and then parse as CSV, or if you parse as CSV first and then UTF7-encode.    Python 2's CSV parser can't handle unicode, but python 2 does have a UTF-7 encoder.  So you can encode, parse, and then decode, and it's as if you had a unicode-capable parser.

```
import csv
import io

def read_csv(path):
    with io.open(path, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\r\n")
    lines = [l.encode('utf7').decode('ascii') for l in lines]
    reader = csv.reader(lines, dialect=csv.excel)
    for row in reader:
        yield [x.encode('ascii').decode('utf7') for x in row]

for row in read_csv("lol.csv"):
    print(repr(row))
```

**lol.csv**

```
foo,bar,foo∆bar,"foo,bar"
```

**output**:

```
[u'foo', u'bar', u'foo\u2206bar', u'foo,bar']
```