# Printing 2d array with Russian characters to a csv with python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, encoding

I have a two dimensional array which has Russian/Arabic/ Chinese characters in it. I am not sure how to print all of it to a CSV file. I would like to print it to the CSV in UTF-8. The code which I am using is listed below.

```
matchedArray = [[]]
matchedArray.append(x)

ar = matchedArray

f1 = open('C:/Users/sagars/Desktop/encoding.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f1)
writer.writerow(['Flat Content', 'Post Dates', 'AuthorIDs', 'ThreadIDs',
                 'Matched Keyword', 'Count of keyword']) #if needed
for values in ar:
    writer.writerow(values)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sagars/PycharmProjects/encoding/encoding.py", line 18, in <module>
    writer.writerow(values)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-13: ordinal not in range(128)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I print this 2D array to the CSV file?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried translating the code?

Comment: I would rather not translate the code for now. The ideal situation would be to print the elements to the file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7 (assuming your `values` are Unicode, else you'll have to decode them into Unicode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode each character using the right encoding before storing to the csv file.

```
for values in ar:
    # values is a list/string of unicode characters
    writer.writerow([val.encode("utf-8") for val in values])
```