# Reading UTF-8 with BOM using Python CSV module causes unwanted extra characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I am trying to read a CSV file with Python with the following code:

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
   c = csv.reader(f)
   for row in c:
      print row
```

My `example.txt` has only the following content:

```
Hello world!
```

For UTF-8 or ANSI encoded files, this gives me the expected output:

```
> ["Hello world!"]
```

But if I save the file as UTF-8 with BOM I get this output:

```
> ["\xef\xbb\xbfHello world!"]
```

Since I do not have any control over what files the user will use as input, I would like this to work with BOM as well. How can I fix this problem? Is there anything I need to do to ensure that this works for other encodings as well?

Comment: NB: whatever solution you use, the important thing is to use `utf-8-sig` for decoding.

Comment: `import csv,csvkit,codecs,unicodecsv

with open("example.txt",'r') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    for row in c:
        print [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]
        
with open("example.txt",'r') as f:
    c = unicodecsv.reader(f)
    for row in c:
        print row
                
with open("example.txt",'r') as f:
    c = csvkit.reader(f)
    for row in c:
        print row`  all prints `[u'\ufeffHello world!']` so i ithink it is not **duplicate**- first try is using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7

Comment: @ekhumoro: The duplicate is border line... Other question is about UTF-8 data while this one is specifically about BOM in utf8 file. The other page only speaks (in only one answer) of BOM for UTF-16 files. Your comment does answer this question but IMHO it would deserve to be an answer on a not duplicate question :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta. Please read the question more carefully (esp. the last paragraph) - it's not only about the utf-8 signature. Also, the highest voted answer in the dup specifically uses `utf-8-sig`; but some of the other answers don't - which is why I added a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

You could make use of the `unicodecsv` Python module as follows:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_reader = unicodecsv.reader(f_input, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    print list(csv_reader)
```

So for an input file containing the following in UTF-8 with BOM:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

It would display the following:

```
[[u'c1', u'c2', u'c3', u'c4', u'c5', u'c6', u'c7', u'c8'], [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8']]
```

The `unicodecsv` module can be installed using `pip` as follows:

```
pip install unicodecsv
```

Comment: but what about `\ufeff`? is not it useless?

Comment: Indeed, I'd put the wrong encoding in, as stated `utf-8-sig` should be used.