# Writing to CSV - set vs list - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, csv, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm building a simple scraper in order to learn python. 
After writing the csvWriter function below, I'm having issues. It seems that the encoding can't be written to csv file (I assume this is because of price information I'm scraping).

Also, I'm wondering if I am correct in thinking that in this case, it is best to go from set -> list to get the information zipped and presented in the way that I want before writing.

Also - any general advice on how I am approaching this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import csv

response = request.get('http://website.com/subdomain/logqueryhere')
baseurl = 'http://website.com'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
hotelInfo = soup.find_all("div", {'class': "hotel-wrap"})

#retrieveLinks: A function to generate a list of hotel URL's to be passed to the price checker.
def retrieveLinks():
    for hotel in hotelInfo:
        urllist = []
        hotelLink  = hotel.find('a', attrs={'class': ''})
        urllist.append(hotelLink['href'])
        scraper(urllist)

hotelnameset = set()
hotelurlset = set()
hotelpriceset = set()

# Scraper: A function to scrape from the lists generated above with retrieveLinks
def scraper(inputlist):
    global hotelnameset
    global hotelurlset
    global hotelpriceset
    #Use a set here to avoid any dupes.
    for url in inputlist:
        fullurl = baseurl + url
        hotelurlset.add(str(fullurl))
        hotelresponse = requests.get(fullurl)
        hotelsoup = BeautifulSoup(hotelresponse.text)
        hoteltitle = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'vcard'})
        hotelhighprice = hotelsoup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pricing'}).text
        hotelpriceset.add(hotelhighprice)
        for H1 in hoteltitle:
            hotelName = hoteltitle.find('h1').text
            hotelnameset.add(str(hotelName))
            time.sleep(2)
    csvWriter()


#csvWriter: A function to write the above mentioned sets/lists to a CSV file.
def csvWriter():
    global hotelnameset
    global hotelurlset
    global hotelpriceset
    csvname = list(hotelnameset)
    csvurl = list(hotelurlset)
    csvprice = list(hotelpriceset)
    #lets zip the values we neded (until we learn a better way to do it)
    zipped = zip(csvname, csvurl, csvprice)
    c = csv.writer(open("hoteldata.csv", 'wb'))
    for row in zipped:
        c.writerow(row)

retrieveLinks()
```

Error is as follows -

```
± |Add_CSV_Writer U:2 ✗| → python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
    retrieveLinks()
  File "main.py", line 18, in retrieveLinks
    scraper(urllist)
  File "main.py", line 44, in scraper
    csvWriter()
  File "main.py", line 60, in csvWriter
    c.writerow(row)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting your actual error will really help!  In any case, in python 2.X the CSV writer does not automatically encode unicode for you.  You essentially have to write your own using unicodecsv (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.0) or use one of the unicode CSV implementations on the web ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7)):

```
import unicodecsv
def csvWriter():
    global hotelnameset
    global hotelurlset
    global hotelpriceset
    csvname = list(hotelnameset)
    csvurl = list(hotelurlset)
    csvprice = list(hotelpriceset)
    #lets zip the values we neded (until we learn a better way to do it)
    zipped = zip(csvname, csvurl, csvprice)
    with open('hoteldata.csv', 'wb') as f_in:
        c = unicodecsv.writer(f_in, encoding='utf-8')
        for row in zipped:
            c.writerow(row)
```