# UnicodeEncodeError with csv.writer

Tags: python, unicode, error-handling

Pardon my ugly newb code, I'm learning. I'm pulling movie data from OMDB API, but when I move it to CSV I get UnicodeEncodeError for many films. Likely because actor names have accents, for instance. I want to 1.) Identify which films are problematic, 2.) skip them, and/or 3.) preferably correct the error. What I have currently just passes the whole thing when an error occurs. Looking for a simple fix, since I'm novice.

```
import csv
import os
import json
import omdb

movie_list = ['A Good Year', 'A Room with a View', 'Anchorman', 'Amélie', 'Annie Hall', 'Before Sunrise']

data_list = []

textdoc = open('textdoc.txt','w')

for w in movie_list:
    x = omdb.request(t=w, fullplot=True, tomatoes=True, r='json')
    y = x.content
    z = json.loads(y)
    data_list.append([z["Title"], z["Year"], z["Actors"], z["Awards"], z["Director"], z["Genre"], z["Metascore"], z["Plot"], z["Rated"], z["Runtime"], z["Writer"], z["imdbID"], z["imdbRating"], z["imdbVotes"], z["tomatoRating"], z["tomatoReviews"], z["tomatoFresh"], z["tomatoRotten"], z["tomatoConsensus"], z["tomatoUserMeter"], z["tomatoUserRating"], z["tomatoUserReviews"]])

try:
    with open('Films.csv', 'w') as g:
        a = csv.writer(g, delimiter=',')
        a.writerow(["Title", "Year", "Actors", "Awards", "Director", "Genre", "Metascore", "Plot", "Rated", "Runtime", "Writer", "imdbID", "imdbRating", "imdbVotes", "tomatoRating", "tomatoReviews", "tomatoFresh", "tomatoRotten", "tomatoConsensus", "tomatoUserMeter", "tomatoUserRating", "tomatoUserReviews"])
        a.writerows(data_list)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print("fail")
```

Comment: just a note, if you did `csv_fields = ["Title", "Year", .. etc.]` then your `data_list.append` could be simplified to `data_list.append([z[field] for field in csv_fields])` and the csv headers just `a.writerow(csv_fields)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out `smart_str`

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
data_list.append(map(smart_str, [z['element1'], z['element2']]))
a.write_row(map(smart_str, ["Title", "Year", "Actors", "Awards", "Director", "Genre", "Metascore", "Plot", "Rated", "Runtime", "Writer", "imdbID", "imdbRating", "imdbVotes", "tomatoRating", "tomatoReviews", "tomatoFresh", "tomatoRotten", "tomatoConsensus", "tomatoUserMeter", "tomatoUserRating", "tomatoUserReviews"]))
a.write_rows(data_list)
```

Comment: `map(lambda x: smart_str(x), ...)` could be replaced with just `map(smart_str, ...)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen good catch :) was making it cluttered.. made the suggested changes

Comment: @Kees as once suggested to me, Say [Hello to Unicode](https://kos.gd/posts/say-hello-to-unicode/) :)

Comment: Thanks, will read up on Unicode. However, oddly I get a syntax error at: `with open('BritAir_100Films.csv', 'w') as g:`

Comment: can you add another `except Exception, e: print e` after your current `except Unicode..` statement and say what the error is? it looks to me something small wrong in the code you're running the line should run perfectly

Comment: @minocha Thanks, I've got it working using your code! I was missing a parenthesis (among other things) but ultimately worked.

Comment: @minocha, thanks I have. But it says I need 15 rep points before I can affect the publicly displayed score.

Comment: @Kees np :) You can still accept my answer with the 'tick' if this solution worked for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 7):

Python 2.x:Instead of `with open("Films.csv", 'w') as g:` you could try to use [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html) in order to open the csv output as `UTF-8` encoding.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('Films.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as g:
# rest of code
```

Python 3.x: try opening `g` with `UTF-8` encoding:

```
with open('Films.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as g:
# rest of code.
```

Comment: I assume your first example should be using `codecs.open`?

Comment: Thanks. However I still get the error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Kees is this occurring with the above code and if so what line? It may be caused by `json.loads` which you should be able to pass `encoding="utf-8"` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If using Python 2, `csvwriter` doesn't really support Unicode, but there is an example in the `csv` documentation to work around it.  An example is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245651/235698).

If using Python 3, then make the following changes:

```
y = x.content.decode('utf8')
```

and

```
with open('Films.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8',newline='') as g:
```

With these changes text is decoded to Unicode for processing within the Python script, and encoded back to UTF-8 when written to a file.  This is the recommended way to deal with Unicode.

`newline=''` is the correct way to open a file for `csv` use.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348664/235698) and the `csv` docs.

You can remove the `try`/`except` as well.  It just suppresses useful tracebacks.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that works for me is to add at the beginning of the export procedure:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```