# How to download CSV with unicode characters in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, unicode

I am downloading and saving in a CSV data using Django but I have problems when the text is not a simple string but Unicode.

This is what I do:

```
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(tuple(corresponding_data[btn]["columns"].split(',')))
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
return response
```

How can I also include unicode text?

**EDITED**

This is the error I get:

> ```
> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

And if I try this:

```
writer = csv.writer(response, encoding='utf-8')
```

I get an error that 'encoding' parameter doesn't exist in this function.

Comment: In Python 3, use the `encoding` parameter when using `open`, not `csv.writer`.  In Python 2, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245651/235698) for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of searching I managed to solve the issue by doing the following:

```
for row in rows:
       field_1 = row[0]
       field_2 = row[1].encode(encoding='UTF-8')
       fields = [field_1, field_2]
       writer.writerows([fields])
```

Explanation:
The first column of the CSV contains numbers. The encoding function doesn't work for numbers. That's why I need to encode only the second column. Then I pass the values in a new list called fields and then I write it in the CSV.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change

```
writer = csv.writer(response)
```

to

```
writer = csv.writer(response, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I tried that but Django keeps throwing errors:  
'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: `csv.writer` doesn't take an encoding parameter in either Python 2 or 3.