# Write nested lists to python - solved encoding issue but code is writing empty rows between rows

Tags: python, csv, python-unicode, eol

I am trying to write a nested list into a csv file, using Python 2.7.

I had encountered encoding issues,

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which I solved using this post:
[Read and Write CSV files including unicode with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7)

This code works fine encoding-wise, but the generated file has empty lines between all its lines:

```
def write_to_file (list_to_write):
    with open(basename_noext+'.csv', 'a') as thefile:
        writer=csv.writer(thefile)
        for row in list_to_write:
            row=[s.encode('utf-8') for s in row]
            writer.writerows([row])
```

If I look in the file, I see an `CRLF` and a `CR` at the end of each line.

**Solution to double lines**:
open the file as binary for append `'ab'`:

```
with open(basename_noext+'.csv', 'ab') as thefile:
```

**Edited** the question to provide the full working code; after finding the answer to the initial question in the duplicate question, I found another bug in the code; I added the solution to this as well

Comment: Can you some sample of your list?

Comment: `[u'n', u'Nationals', u'1044', u'Norwegian(Bokm\xe5l)']`is a sample element, the one where the program breakes