# How can I fix this warning:UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

guys I got a warning when I run a code I got this warning two times:

`UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal`located at `if result2=b and c == 'Pass':`

thing is going wired because I use `if result2=b and c == 'Pass':` three time, only last two have warning. I cannot found some solution on Internet,but they are not work for my code. Here is my code, please help me with that. Thx in advanced!

```
def XXX1():
    XXXXXX
    if result2==b and c == 'Failed':       ----------no warning
    XXXXXX

def XXX2():
    XXXXXX
    if result2==b and c == 'Failed':       ----------warning
    XXXXXX

def XXX3():
    XXXXXX
    if result2==b and c == 'Pass':         ----------warning
    XXXXXX
```

some parameters may help:

```
with open('1.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Case Id']== 'getpropertyvalue_without_propertyname' :
            a=row['Result Link']
            c=row['Status']


url = a
html = requests.get(url,verify=False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

result = soup.find("p", {"class":"ERRORLevel"})
result2=result.text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Unicode strings and bytestrings. Python 2 will try to decode the bytestring (as ASCII) when making comparisons, and when that fails you'll get a warning:

```
>>> u'å', u'å'.encode('utf8')
(u'\xe5', '\xc3\xa5')
>>> 'å' == u'å'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

Don't mix Unicode strings and bytestrings. Decode your text data as early as possible, and only compare Unicode objects. In the above example, the bytestring is UTF-8 encoded, so decoding as UTF-8 first would resolve the warning.

For your example code, BeautifulSoup is (correctly) producing Unicode text. You'll have to decode your CSV data, see [Read and Write CSV files including unicode with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7) for solutions, or decode those two strings manually with `str.decode()` calls.