# Trying to extract data from a table and there are foreign characters keeping me from writing to a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, non-ascii-characters

i'm extracting data but some special characters will causing an error

```
from unicodedata import normalize


import codecs
import csv
import urllib2
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ratebeer.com/top'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody')

list_of_rows = []


for row in table.findAll('tr'):
list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./top50.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

trying to extract a csv to import to excel with 50 top beer, rank,name,style,brewery, rating

Comment: You should not open the `outfile` as binary and set an appropriate `encoding` as parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and Write CSV files including unicode with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

This is working, python 3.6, defined parser `features="lxml"`, and encoding `encoding='utf-8'`:

```
import codecs, csv, urlib, requests
from unicodedata import normalize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ratebeer.com/top'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
table = soup.find('tbody')

list_of_rows = []

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./top50.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pandas? You can specify encoding which handles the characters  `encoding='utf-8-sig'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.ratebeer.com/top', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
table = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
table.drop(['Unnamed: 5'], axis=1, inplace = True)
table.columns = ['Rank', 'Name', 'Count', 'Abv', 'Score']
table.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```